# Apicurio registry client - enable logging of REST communication via OkHttpClient

Tags: rest, logging, apache-kafka, okhttp, apicurio-registry

I have a Spring Boot application which sends some message to Kafka. We use Apicurio registry provided by our customer to manage AVRO schema for message serialization. The application  uses Apicurio registry client, namely the Maven artifact [`io.apicurio:apicurio-registry-utils-converter:1.3.2.Final`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.apicurio/apicurio-registry-utils-converter/1.3.2.Final) and its dependency [`apicurio-registry-utils-serde`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.apicurio/apicurio-registry-utils-serde/1.3.2.Final). The client communicates with registry using REST API.

Recently the Apicurio was migrated to higher version and there are some issues with REST communication. (They are beyond scope of this question - in a nutshell, we play with changing global id strategy to avoid some unwanted REST calls, more info in comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74076818/653539).)

The Apicurio migration seems somewhat turbulent and I observe now that any REST call can fail with various reason (missing configuration, missing artifacts, availability...). Actually the only thing in log is `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` without further cause description. To understand what's happening there, I need to enable logging of all REST API calls from Apicurio client.

The Apicurio client internally uses `OkHttpClient`. I am aware the `OkHttpClient` is configured using builder pattern and the standard way is to [add HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/StubbornJava/StubbornJava/blob/master/stubbornjava-examples/src/main/java/com/stubbornjava/examples/okhttp/OkHttpLogging.java#L38). However, the process of creation of `OkHttpClient` seems to be too strictly [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) in internals of Apicurio client (`private static OkHttpClient createHttpClientWithConfig` in `RegistryRestClientImpl`). Hence the Apicurio client itself does not let user to set up custom configuration of underlying `OkHttpClient`.

**Is there some way to do it in a simple way or am I missing something?**

(Note some of these `application.properties` settings which were recommended to us are helpful too but they does not relate to core topic of question:

```
logging.level.okhttp3=TRACE
logging.level.org.apache.http=TRACE
logging.level.io.apicurio=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=TRACE
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=TRACE
```

)

Answer (score 2):

After browsing Apicurio client source, the only way I know is following.
Caution: it is very dirty but works.

1. get access to `OkHttpClient`

   - start with autowired Spring bean `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`
   - create auxiliary `KafkaProducer` which instantiates `AvroKafkaSerializer` as `valueSerializer`
   - go through reference chain `AvroKafkaSerializer.client -> CompatibleClient.delegate -> RegistryRestClientImpl.httpClient` finally to `OkHttpClient`
2. tweak `OkHttpClient`

   - The builder is gone and `OkHttpClient`'s interceptor list is final and immutable. Fortunately the list is just `Collections.unmodifiableList` hence we can invade into underlying list and modify it.

Whole solution:

```
# application.properties
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.AvroKafkaSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.properties.apicurio.registry.url=${apicurio.registry.url}
...
```

```
@Component
public class Service {

    private final DefaultKafkaProducerFactory defaultKafkaProducerFactory;

    Service(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory defaultKafkaProducerFactory) {
        this.defaultKafkaProducerFactory = defaultKafkaProducerFactory;

        Producer producer = defaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer();
        KafkaProducer delegate = field(producer,"delegate");
        AvroKafkaSerializer valueSerializer = field(delegate, "valueSerializer");
        CompatibleClient client = field(valueSerializer, "client");
        RegistryRestClientImpl rest = field(client, "delegate");
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = field(rest, "httpClient");
        List unmodifiableInterceptorList = field(okHttpClient, "interceptors");
        List modifiable = field(unmodifiableInterceptorList, "list");
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(Level.BASIC);
        modifiable.add(loggingInterceptor);
    }

    static <T> T field(Object instance, String fieldName) {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(instance.getClass(), fieldName);
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        return (T)ReflectionUtils.getField(field, instance);
    }

}
```

Yes it's awful. I will be happy to reaccept to better answer.

Comment: You should only need reflection for the private http client, not your producer factory. Also, with the Confluent Avro serializer, I know it has a public constructor to accept a RegistryClient, so Apicurio does not? In any case, the "better solution" would be to fork or create a feature request PR

Comment: Yes, formally there exists `AvroKafkaSerializer(RegistryService client)` constructor but it is never called. The library actually calls no-arg `AvroKafkaSerializer()` constructor and some super constructor *instantiates* `RegistryService` based on configuration properties. The field is protected so - again - not accessible without hacks. Alternatively I could define `MyAvroKafkaSerializer extends AvroKafkaSerializer` and in constructor assign the client instance to some global place but it would spare only single reflection call. Anyway thanks for your comment.